# Open source file from NUnit's GUI Test Runner

Tags: nunit

Is there a plugin or configuration option that will open a source file in Visual Studio when the relevant line is clicked in NUnit's GUI test runner?  It displays it in NUnit, but that still leaves me searching for the file in Visual Studio to actually fix the error.

[image: Screenshot of NUnit's GUI runner with line number circled]

Comment: You can use VS2012 and Nunit.Adapter http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=vsTestAdapter&r=2.6

Comment: @slava - works for me.  Post a full answer so I can give you credit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use http://nunit.org/index.php?p=vsTestAdapter&r=2.6.2

> NUnit adapter for integrated test execution under Visual Studio 2012
>   (all updates),and Visual Studio 2013 (all updates). Compatible with
>   NUnit 2.0 through 2.6.3.

[Download](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=download)

[image]

Comment: The link to latest information on the adapter is http://nunit.org/index.php?p=vsTestAdapter&r=2.6.3.    The download link above is to NUnit itself.  The adapter can be found at either the Visual Studio Gallery at https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6ab922d0-21c0-4f06-ab5f-4ecd1fe7175d  or as a nuget package at http://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnitTestAdapter/

Comment: Thanks for this. I hope it helps other developers to use nunit.